# Unable to connect to oracledb in Node.js due to error at getConnection()

Tags: javascript, oracle, docker, jenkins, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect to oracledb on nodejs while running scripts via jenkins.
I have an image created which uses a docker image "FROM NODE 14.17.4" which is based on Linux.

I have used oracle instantclient_21_6 and have added the right LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However while running the script I get below error at getConnection:
DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

```
oracledb.TNS_ADMIN = process.cwd + "path";

async function run (){
oracledb.autoCommit = true;

let connection;

connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
  user: `user`,
  password: `pwd`,
  connectString: `string`
})
.....
}
```

I did go through a number of documents but not able to fix this. The connection works for me on local which is windows OS but fails in jenkins. Appreciate any help

Comment: Where have you added LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Are you sure it is set within the context of Jenkins' shell, where the connection is happening?

Comment: hello, I have added LD_LIBRARY_PATH in package.json which calls the js file so the PATH is definitey being picked up. syntax: "ACH" : "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/linux_client/instantclient_21_6:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ach_conf.js"

Comment: Is your Oracle instant client and your Node.js both 64-bit? You cannot mix the architecture.

Comment: Yes, both are 64-bit

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH that way is obviously not working.  Triple check you have the right directory and that it is readable by your process.  Make sure there are no security 'features' either wiping out LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or limiting access to /linux_client.  Maybe you can you use `ldconfig` instead (see node-oracledb installation instructions)?

Comment: There is no node-oracledb property `oracledb.TNS_ADMIN`.  Hopefully you are just using this for something in your app.  If you want to set the network configuration file directory at runtime, use `oracledb.initOracleClient({configDir: process.cwd + "path"});`, see the doc https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones. I added console.log(`LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ${process.cwd() + process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`); and this returns the correct path. I am not sure on how ldconfig is to be used as I am new to linux. However I added ldconfig -p and this lists the files and directories in cache `/etc/ld.so.cache'. However I still get the same error. Can you please help on how to use ldconfig as I guess I am doing that wrong.

Comment: `ldconfig` is explained in both the Instant Client installation instructions and the node-oracledb installation instructions better than I can explain in a comment. For example see https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#install-the-free-oracle-instant-client-basic-zip-file

Comment: Try moving Instant Client to a subdirectory under /opt or /usr/local